# Recently published iOS game's score reporting does not work

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have a recently published iOS game named GuessTheNum. It has a Game Center feature in it. When I was testing it in Sandbox while I was developing it, it had no problem regarding score reporting and leaderboard communication. However, I can not report scores right now, after it has been reviewed and published. Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a few days for Apple servers to update. I had a similar problem some time ago, it repaired on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope it works fine as you mentioned.